# ошибка "mysql not found in the config.ini file", когда скрипт в автозагрузке

Tags: mysql, python, linux

OC Linux;
Написал пару скриптов, основу работы с mysql взял от сюда [ссылка](http://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/article_2190.html)

Данные для подкл. записал в config.ini, весь листинг взял с раздела"Подключение к базе данных MySQL с помощью объекта MySQLConnection".

config.ini:

```
[mysql]
host = localhost
database = python_mysql
user = root
password =
```

connect.py:

```
def read_db_config(filename='config.ini', section='mysql'):

    parser = ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)

    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        items = parser.items(section)
        for item in items:
            db[item[0]] = item[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('{0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db
```

Запускаю скрипт на Python из под пользователя - работает, запросы проходят. 
Заливаю скрипт в init.d, перезагружаю, скрипт работает, запросы не проходят, пишет: "mysql not found in the config.ini file".

Попробовал не использовать config.ini и прописал так:

```
...
conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                       database='python_mysql',
                                       user='root',
                                       password='secret')
...
```

Перезагрузил - скрипт работает, запросы проходят.

Почему, когда скрипт в автозапуске, ругается на config.ini ?
Есть какие-то предположения или может кто-то сталкивался?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, что, просто,надо было прописать полный путь к файлу config.ini.
Надо сделать перерыв...

P.S.
Вот, почему, стоит задать вопрос и я сразу сам нахожу решение.

Comment: Можно еще запросить у интерпретатора абсолютный путь к текущему скрипту, из чего узнать папку, в которой он лежит, и получить абсолютный путь к config.ini. Это немного более универсально, чем задавать абсолютный путь руками.

Comment: Да, это может избавить от многих проблем в будущем...